# Published asp.net website throws Failed to open the connection reportname{} .rpt

Tags: .net, mysql, crystal-reports

I published my asp.net 4.0 application into server machine But whenever i am opening report pages throws  "Failed to open the connection reportname{} .rpt".
i am using ODBC, .net framwork 4.0 and DB as MYSQL.

Comment: check your connection string or odbc properties..

Comment: sicko, but it was working fine in my local sys

Comment: is the odbc connection setup on the server?

Comment: thats why u have to checked the connection string and also (as Lee mentioned), check the odbc connection setup in the server. The connection string that u used in your local could be different from the server